# How to repair .net framework 4.6.1 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

I installed Windows 10 on my PC, but via some trouble with software, my .net framework 4.6.1 is corrupted. I tried to run clean up tool, tried to run repair tool, but they didn't help.

- [Repair tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30135) said that couldn't fix my issue.
- [Clean up tool](http://betanews.com/2015/08/03/net-check-and-repair-tools-now-support-windows-10/) said that took off info about installed framework but looks like did nothing at all.

I have tried to play with PoweShell a bit but without success.

Have anybody had such issue and how to fix it?

Comment: What makes you think your .NET Framework installation is corrupt?

Comment: @Ramhound When I open my asp.net mvc project that requires 4.6.1 version of .net Visual Studio said that I don't have required version of .net framework and redirect me to download page. Downloaded installer can't be installed.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have installed?

Comment: @Ramhound VS2015 update1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue in the next steps:

1. Rollback my operation system to first restore point that I had.
2. Reinstall everything that I want to install.

It isn't smart way to fix it - but it solved my issue.